# Searching MySQL with AES Encryption

Tags: php, mysql, search, aes

I am just curious if someone can get me pointed in the right direction with searching MySQL with AES encryption.

There are a couple of things that need to be considered. If I take the keyword and encrypt it before searching, i'm comparing encryption to encryption and even if one letter is cap and another letter isn't cap inside MySQL then it won't find it using the LIKE %$keyword%

The other factor is my process of encryption.
$variable -> clean-up extra spacing -> strip_slashes (etc) -> Convert to AES -> Convert to Base_64 before importing to DB.

The reason for the extra encoding was issues with abstract characters going into MySQL and this was a flawless import using this. So using MySQL AES built in, wasn't the best option for me.

So I'm guessing that the best route to do this is something along these lines.

$variable -> [keyword]
Do a sql results decrypt it and search the string? but that seems kind of overkill...

Perhaps someone can shed some light onto this for me, I would be surely grateful.

Cheers! and thanks in advance!

Comment: Would it be better for me to leave all my data decrypted in the DB except for very-important information? Currently it holds information IE: SIN, DOB, ADDRESS, ALL CONTACT, etc... it's heavy amount of data in one spot but I am not sure if it would be just smart to encrypt the SIN and leave the rest plain-text... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have encrypted the data before inserting it, there is no way to search partial values *at all* except to iterate each row, decrypt it, and search the result.

Comment: What do you think about the comment I added above to my question?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a slow response, however you could get much faster search results by doing something like this.

Let's say we want to encrypt these sentences:

1. My nice car
2. I love mysql
3. Minority

You could store them encrypted, let's assume ********* or, your could store the encrypted value and include the first 3 characters of the original: my *********, I l*********, Min*********

In this case you could use mysql to search the first 3 characters of what you're looking for and perform a full decryption on the rest of the data.

Of course this only works for searches that "start with" a certain string. The 3 characters is just a random number and should be determined based on the sensitivity, performance needs and dataset size.

Comment: Yeah that's an interesting thought actually, I will have to consider this too for future use! Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example similar to what Andrew suggested if it helps.

$sql_query = "SELECT *, AES_DECRYPT(text_in_blob,'$salt') AS decrypted_text FROM my_table WHERE CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(`text_in_blob`,'$salt') USING latin1) LIKE '%keyword%' " ;